# Does anybody know what these white flickering blotches are?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I will start by saying, i rendered at low samples so I can test whether this problem still remains. So noise artifacts are present, but on the left side specifically, there is this persistent problem where the grass develops these “flickering white spots” after rendering… it sort of looks like the hdri’s color is spilling through the plants. the plants are being projected onto the plane as seperate particle systems.

my partner and I copied the planes with the plant instance objects over to a new blank project, and rendered out 100 frames on 100 samples, and the problem did not remain. So this eliminates any speculation of overlapping animation, z-fighting, and theres no hidden duplicates in render. These arent fireflies, these are huge white spots popping up in some sort of flickering pattern. I feel like i’ve narrowed it down to it being something specifically wrong in this project file’s settings.

I’m not sure if this is some sort of setting causing some post processing errors of some sort. I’m out of ideas, we’ve been trouble shooting this for days.

I have no idea what this could be. Any thoughts? I am rendering on cycles, blender 3.2.

Here is the link to the render which is showcasing the problem. They are very prominent on the left side, you will notice them right away. Thank you!

[Link to video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NE5Sc9CT4Zs2PXxyKiB2d_vjx0sJ7hwo/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Denoising is the first thought? Is it on? What's it like with it off?

Comment: @RobinBetts unfortunately denoising was off in render, somewhere tkwards the middle are where fireflies are appearing since my team and I rendered on very low samples for this test. But on the left side this flickering effect is happening, and no matter how many samples we render frames on, they remain. Any other thoughts?.. i dont even know how to replicate the issue, we brought the planes with the plants(which have animation on them) into another project and the problem didnt seem to persist. Really wacky, I’ve never seen anything like this.

Comment: My only thoughts (probably not worth much) are that the bright pixels are _coherent_ in space and time, sometimes over more than one frame,and there's at least one case of a smooth color-change, frame to frame. This suggests a genuine (if unnatural-looking) interpretation of the light-response of surfaces by the renderer, rather than random noise.What changes did 'another project' involve?